# Close App When 2nd Form Closes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I've looked all over for a way to close the program if the 2nd form is closed

I have a `boolean` that is Set to True if the 2nd form is visible, but when the frmCourses.visible Check goes, I get the error in Debug mode `An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in HomeWork Helper.exe`

```
If Ready Then
        If frmCourses.Visible = False Then
            Application.Exit()
        End If
End if
```

Comment: `HomeWork Helper.exe` ? I always wanted to have this file in school! Serious mode on, please provide more details. Ideally something we can reproduce.

Comment: Pay attention to the exception message.  Do *not* create UI on a worker thread.

Comment: @Neolisk HomeWork Helper is a program I'm developing entirely myself. It serves as a reminder for homework, projects and test. I.E. you will get a balloon notification on your task bar that says: Reminder! You have {ThisProject} due during {WhichPeriod} For {ThisClass}

Comment: And when it's finished it will become Open-Source

Comment: Have you searched online, maybe something like this is already available? Or you are doing this as part of learning/training?

Comment: While I'm learning VB/C#, I'm doing this more as a way to help me with my school work. I've done hours of research and nothing seems to fit my needs, so I want to be able to design the program in a way that suits my personal needs. It's more of a way to help people who have conditions like I do (Autism), and to keep them more on track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 2nd Form, create a method for `Form2_FormClosed`

This code will be added:

```
Private Sub Form2_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed

End Sub
```

Inside the Sub, add `Application.Exit()`

Result (With a Comment):

```
Private Sub Form2_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    'Closes the Application if the 2nd Form is Closed
    Application.Exit()
End Sub
```